# Removing %20 from URL parameters

Tags: javascript

I know you need to use some variant of decodeURIComponent() to do something like this, but since I'm still fairly new to coding and using some code I found on the net for my purposes, I'm not sure how to go about changing it to suit my needs.

What I have is a function that gets each URL parameter I need out of the URL (of which there are many). I have to use these variables for other functions as parameters and also to display on the page, and I can't get the %20's to disappear.

```
function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
            });
            return vars;
        }
```

Where I get each variable using:

```
var markname = getUrlVars()["mname"];
```

I've tried to put decodeURIComponent() in different places in that function, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm also not sure if it needs to use value or vars.

```
value = decodeURIComponent(value);
```

Or something like that...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is an example value that is wrong (that you want decoded)?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent()` is what you are looking for. Can you provide an example of what exactly went wrong?

Comment: My URL looks something like this:

`?mapid=1h2pwR4ULN3GHAENYtww-gINXMgvxAaHBu5waliI&mapname=test&jnumber=1234&updated=01/01/01&marker=3&mname=Driver%20Reviver%20Locations`

So something like Driver Reviver Locations would need to be displayed on screen, and is appearing as Driver%20Reviver%20Locations. In some cases as well, these variables need to be plugged in to functions, and I'm worried if I don't curb all the %anything that eventually it'll screw up on itself.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1048572) for a 100% working solution (or the whole question for an overview)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent` as you posted should work fine. You might as well replace plus signs with spaces, and don't forget to decode the `key` as well:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var url = window.location.href,
        vars = {};
    url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
         key = decodeURIComponent(key);
         value = decodeURIComponent(value);
         vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much. I didn't realize I needed to do both. Is there a reason why both key and value need to be decoded?

Comment: I can't say it happens often, but of course keys could contain encoded characters.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass the url use 
`str_replace(" ","-",$name)`
and decode it by
`str_replace("-"," ",$p->property_name)`

it will remove space and add - in the url

Answer (score 0):

simply do this `("your string here").replaceAll(" ", "-")`